# Unable to log into Hyperledger cello operator dashboard

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-cello

I just installed hyperledger cello following the instructions [here](https://hyperledger-cello.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_master/) The operator dashboard opens up at port 8080 but when I try logging in with the credentials admin:pass as suggested by [tutorials](https://medium.com/@pvrforpranavvr/hyperledger-cello-setup-f31954a9551f) [like](https://github.com/hyperledger/cello/blob/master/docs/scenario.md) [these](https://hyperledger-cello.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/), a spinner appears on the login button for a while and then the button becomes active again. 
Are there any other credentials one can use to log into the operator dashboard? I can't log into the operator dashboard and I can't access the user dashboard. The user dashboard container is not running and there's nothing running on my port 8081 where the user dashboard should be. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you are running the service under dev mode, and if you run dev mode, must compile js files for operator dashboard, if not operator dashboard can't find any js files needed, so after you login the page is empty. In the latest code, will compile js files if you run it in dev mode, such as:

```
MODE=dev make start
```

So please try again after you clone the latest code, and if you also have any problem, can comment more here.

And We have released v0.9.0-alpha version, and in the newest version have some new feature, include:

- Support kubernetes agent.
- Can apply fabric 1.2 chain in user dashboard, and use it.

And this is the new tutorial, in this tutorial include:

- How to setup master service.
- How to setup k8s, docker worker node.
- How to create host for k8s, docker type in operator dashboard.
- How to create chain in operator dashboard.
- Apply & Use fabric chain in user dashboard, include fabric v1.0 & v1.2.